# MVC ModelState.IsValid=true with a null required property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this Model

```
public class ModelVM
{
    private string _rD;
    [Required]
    public string RD
    {
        get
        {
            return _rD;
        }
        set
        {
            _rD = RCodes.Contains(value)? value : null;
        }
    }

    private static List<string> RCodes = new List<string>
    {
        "OK",
        "OTHER",
        "ANOTHER"
    };
}
```

In my MVC Controller

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(ModelVM modelVM, FormCollection collection)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return Json(new
            {
                Result = "ERROR",
                Message = "Missing fields."
            });

        return Json("OK");
    }
}
```

I send: `{ RD: "Whatever" }`

And in debugging `ModelState.IsValid=true`. I have a similar code on a WebApi Controller and works as I expect (`modelstate.valid=false`)

Do you have some ideas why MVC is doing that? or what is wrong with my code?

Comment: During debugging what value is stored in `modelVM.RD` if you put a breakpoint on the if statement.

Comment: `ModelState.IsValid` tells you if any model errors have been added to `ModelState`. In this case it is true because there are no errors in  the ModelState. You said that you sent  `{ RD: "Whatever" }`. default model binder will look at the data sent and match the properties with the intended type. From a binding perspective the `[Required]` validation was met because when the binder looked at the dictionary the required property `RD` was provided in the incoming data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ModelState.IsValid` tells you if any model errors have been added to ModelState.

In this case it is valid because there are no client side errors in the provided data that would affect ModelState.

You said...

> I sent { RD: "Whatever" }

...which would mean that the model binder will look at the data sent and match the properties with the intended type. From a model binding perspective the `[Required]` validation was met because when the binder looked at the route value dictionary for the required property `RD`, it was provided by the client in the incoming data.

If you want to manually invalidate the state you can...

```
public ActionResult Index(ModelVM modelVM, FormCollection collection)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
        if(modelVM.RD == null) {
            ModelState.AddModelError("RD", "RD is invalid.");
        }
    }

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return Json(new
        {
            Result = "ERROR",
            Message = "Missing fields."
        });

    return Json("OK");
}
```

Comment: Hrmm, I did not want to do that, but I suppose, I have to. Do you know why with a WebApi controller tha same logic ([required], _rD = RDCodes.ValidMethod...) does ModelState.IsValid=false?

Comment: The code may look the same and used in the same way but the logic used in web api was not the same as in MVC. That is why in vNext version they merged the code base back into one.